# I want to render one page block section on the page to certain user only.

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I want to render one page block section on the page to certain user only.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!$User.Name == opp.Security_Officer_Name__c}">
<apex:inputfield />
</apex:pageBlocksectionItem>
```

above code gives me an error for `$User.Name` Error Message "Field Name does not exist. Check spelling." and starange part is if I use `$User.FirstName` it works fine.

Does anyone know reason behind this? Any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is strange, but my best guess is that the Name field is actually a composite field which gets some magic treatment in the backend. I notice that both FirstName and Lastname work, so perhaps you should use something like
`{!$User.FirstName &' '& $User.LastName == opp.Security_Officer_Name__c}`
 or find a way to match on something other than Name...

Comment: your code helped me matching the first name and last name of the user. I don't need suffix name or anything from that Name field composition. So I better of using it your suggested way.  Many thanks